# How to disable foreign key constraints in Postgres dump file?

Tags: foreign-key, psql, pg-dump

I used `pg_dump -U postgres -p 65432 --table=tableName --data-only --column-inserts DBName>fileName.sql` to dump one particular table's rows. Now I need to insert them to another database but I get this error

> insert or update on table "tableName" violates foreign key constraint "tableName_fk1"

How to proceed by dropping the foreign key contraint?

Comment: Do you have the data for the table referred to by the foreign key constraint? In that case you should load that data first. Otherwise you can drop a constraint using `ALTER TABLE tableName DROP CONSTRAINT tableName_fk1;`. No need to keep the constraint if you don't have the data it refers to.

Comment: I do not have any data it refers to. I just want the rows to be inserted into the table. DROP CONSTRAINT worked like a charm,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the command is:

```
alter table "tableName" drop constraint "tableName_fk1"
```

The foreign key must already exist in the database where you want to import, since the dump was made --data-only.